# Contenante string which contains value of variable and strings in c:forEach loop in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to achieve this:

```
  ['string1', -33.890542, 151.274856],
  ['string 2', -33.923036, 151.259052],
  ['string 3', -34.028249, 151.157507],
  ['string 4', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
  ['string 5', -33.950198, 151.259302]
```

To achieve above output I have below code

```
<c:forEach items="${coordListEvent}" var="cor" varStatus="stat">
     <c:set var="chaine" value="     ['',${chaine}${cor.longitude},${cor.latitude}]," />
      </c:forEach>
```

but, I getting result

```
['',['',['',['',['',['',['',['',['',['',10.1803501,36.8162982],10.1803501,36.8162982],10.1803501,36.8162982],10.1803501,36.8162982],10.1803501,36.8162982],10.1803501,36.8162982],10.1803501,36.8162982],10.1803501,36.8162982],10.1803501,36.8
```

How can I modify my code to get expected output?

Comment: Your desired structure is unclear. How do you want the results to look like?

Comment: ['place1', cor.longitude, cor.longitude],
   ['place2', cor.longitude, cor.longitude],
 ['place3', cor.longitude, cor.longitude],
  ['plac4', cor.longitude, cor.longitude],
 ['place5', cor.longitude, cor.longitude]
i want some thing like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `<c:choose>` JSTL tag to branch into an *if-else* construct based on the loop counter.

```
<c:forEach items="${coordListEvent}" var="cor" varStatus="stat">
    <c:choose>
        <!-- IF -->
        <c:when test="${stat.count == 1}">
            <c:set var="chaine" value="[${cor.longitude},${cor.latitude}]" />
        </c:when>
        <!-- ELSE -->
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:set var="chaine" value="${chaine},[${cor.longitude},${cor.latitude}]" />
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your ansewer, but it doesn't  concatenate the first value when count =1 on chaine

Comment: Ah, I missed the `${}` around. Please try again.